# SQL query date range saved in 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table (*Hire Rates*) which contains multiple records. I'm trying to find records based on a date query but cannot get it to work correctly.

Essentially I am looking for records that contain a date between two dates. If my query date is "2021-08-15", it should return the third row (3000) as the query date falls between the two dates.

It is mostly working for me, except if the query date is equal to the start date or end date - in that case it doesn't return any result.

**Table**

| startDate | endDate | hireRate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-05 | 2350 |
| 2021-03-06 | 2021-04-08 | 2890 |
| 2021-04-09 | 2021-09-15 | 3000 |

**Query**

```
$sql = "SELECT rate, currencyID FROM hire_rates WHERE status = '1' AND NOT (startDate >= '$queryDate' OR endDate <= '$queryDate')
```

Comment: If you are *looking for records that contain a date between two dates* then why do you use NOT in your query?

Answer (score 0):

You would pass in the date you care about *as a parameter*.  Then you can use `between` (based on your description of the logic):

```
SELECT rate, currencyID
FROM hire_rates
WHERE status = 1 AND
      ? BETWEEN startDate AND endDate;
```

Where `?` is a parameter for the date you are passing in.

For 2021-08-15, you can write:

```
WHERE status = 1 AND
      '2021-08-15' BETWEEN startDate AND endDate;
```

If you want the current date, you can actually get that from the database:

```
SELECT rate, currencyID
FROM hire_rates
WHERE status = 1 AND
      curdate() BETWEEN startDate AND endDate;
```

Comment: When I try this I can't get it to work. 

So I've done:

SELECT rate, currencyID 
FROM hire_rates
WHERE status = 1 AND 
startDate BETWEEN '2021-08-15' AND '2021-08-15' 

But it doesn't return what I'm expecting. 

Incidentally, I just put in todays date as an example - it would be based on a historic date.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'between' condition.
Like
`select rate, currencyId from hire_rates where states =1 and not (cast($queryDate as DATE) between cast(startDate As DATE) and cast(endDate AS DATE) )`

Answer (score 0):

Just try this then, `$sql = SELECT hireRate FROM hire_rate WHERE startDate<= '$queryDate' and  endDate >= '$queryDate'
[image: see this image]